# How to optimise contraction of three inner tensor indices

Tags: numpy, tensor, blas

In my code for my convolutional neural network there is a step which involves a tensor contraction along 3 dimensions; in NumPy it looks like this (however I am planning on using raw BLAS):

```
y = np.einsum('abcijk,ijkd->abcd', x, f)
```

which is symbolic for

[image]

Generally, CNN routines tackle large tensor contractions by converting higher-dimensional tensors into 2-D "images", then using regular matrix multiplication - the cost and redundancy of the initial dimension reduction is offset by leveraging the speed of GEMM and other well-optimised matrix multiplication routines.

My method involves skipping the dimension reduction stage, and the only real computational effort required is in the tensor multiplication of X and F. Do there exist similarly fast routines for contracting the inner indices of tensors? How can I whittle this down to something that is well-established in BLAS etc.? The fact that *only* inner indices are being contracted suggests to me that there should be a way to take advantage of the locality of reference via the natural traversal order, rather than using generic routines such as ["GETT"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00145).

Comment: If you reshape the 'ijk' dimensions to one, `np.dot` or `np.matmul` should work,

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, that was a massive speed-up right there!